# SQL databases, Date type, and timezones (ADO.NET)

Tags: datetime, ado.net

We're have a problem where a program making a select query is in one timezone, the database is in another, and the date comparisons are including an extra day. I'm guessing this is because saying @date < '2013-01-04' where @date is set as a parameter in the UK, but is for a database in the US, because of the timezone difference, the timeoffset part moves it into the next day.

A DateTime in a database is fundamentally an integer (or long). So how does this work with ADO.NET when the database has a Date column value of 2013-01-04T00:00:00 - is that stored as a UTC DateTime, a local DateTime (whatever offset local happens to be at that point), or a specific offset?

And when I set that parameter with a DateTime (Kind == Local), how does that translate?

thanks - dave

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the database. But it is certainly incorrect to say that all databases across the board store datetimes as one single integer (like dot Net or javascript does).  You don't specify in your question which database product you are using but SQL Server for example uses ***two*** integers:

SQL Server's internal representation for datetime and smalldatetime values is a two part value the first part of which is an integer representing the number of days since 1 Jan 1900, and the second part is a decimal fraction representing the fractional portion of one day (for the time) --- So the integer value 0 (zero) always translates directly into Midnight morning of 1 Jan 1900.

The second part, the time portion is internally also an integer, representing the number of clock-ticks since midnight.  See [this](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2004/datetime-datatype/).  Clock-ticks are 1/300th of a second, about 3.333 milliseconds.

Comment: Yes but... Number of days and seconds since Jan 1 where? A value of 0 in England is a negative number in Colorado.

Answer (score 0):

If you store a .NET DateTime it will always have the same value in the database as .ToString()

It will not specify the timezone.

I recommend that you use `.ToUniversalTime()` in all date times before storing them into your database and assume all of the are UTC when reading them.